# Issue with sending mail in django using gmail smtp server as a test base

Tags: django, smtp, gmail

I am just trying to send a test message before I try to access the main smtp server.
I am trying to send it through the django shell.

This is what I am including

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
email = EmailMessage('test subject', 'test body', to=['me@me.com'])
email.send()
```

I have tried other alternatives and the shell just hangs and I have to ctrl-C out. Here is the trace

```
    send_mail('test email', 'hello world', 'me@me.com', ['me@me.com'],fail_silently=False)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 62, in   send_mail
    connection=connection).send()

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 255, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 88, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()

    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 49, in open
    local_hostname=DNS_NAME.get_fqdn())

    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 249, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)

    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 309, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)

    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 284, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)

    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 562, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)

    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)

    KeyboardInterrupt
```

And here are the settings.

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='not@myemail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='notmypwd'
```

I have went through half a dozen posts on this site and random blogs and nothing has worked thus far so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Thanks for the help.

```
email = EmailMessage('test subject', 'test body', to=['me@me.com'])
email.send()
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: test subject
From: webmaster@localhost
To: me@me.com
Date: Tue, 09 Jul 2013 21:14:59 -0000
Message-ID: <20130709211459.7695.30351@ubuntu>

test body
```

Comment: How long does it hang if you do not `Ctrl+C` out?

Comment: Indefinitely it seems.

Comment: What if you change `smtp.gmail.com` with something you are sure does not exist?

Comment: It hangs as well. I just don't know if it's for the same reason or not.

Comment: What if you change the port number? Are you running Django on your local machine or on hosted service? Is there any firewall involved in any way?

Comment: I'm running it in a virtual machine with no real security for testing purposes so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: what is your `EMAIL_BACKEND` setting?

Comment: There isn't one to my knowledge. There is no EMAIL_BACKEND is the settings whatsoever so it never crossed my mind. Is that an issue though? I thought that as long as you are using another service it wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: No. it is `smtp` by default, so you should be fine. For testing purposes though, I would set the backend to `dummy` and see if something prints on the console: `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`

Comment: I left it running since I posted and it gave me a [Errno 101] Network is unreachable so looking into that now. Guess I didn't wait a full 20 min. The magic number hah.

Comment: I added the output of the result after making the change that you gave me. Waiting and seeing if something will come through now. Is there a reason why that made a difference?

Comment: Guess it dropped somewhere. I'll look at it later when I get home. Thanks for the help/advice I think I will be able to troubleshoot it now at least.

Comment: Did you check your proxy config? Can you reach the server by doing telnet from the shell? `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`